# How to access the attribute from a constant constructor in the constructor initialiser list?

Tags: dart, constructor, initialization, constants

I am having trouble understanding how constant constructors and the constructor initializer list in dart.

I have this small code:

```dart
class A {
  const A();
}

class B {
  const B();

  final A a = const A();
}

class C {
  const C(): a = const A();

  final A a;
}

class D {
  const D(): b = const B();

  final B b;
}

class E {
  const E(): a = const B().a;  // <- Lint: Invalid constant value

  final A a;
}
```

All of these classes and their constructors are legit. Except for `E` and `E()` constructor.

---

What I don't understand is that the `D` constructor is valid:

```dart
const C(): a = const A();
```

But `E` is not valid:

```dart
const E(): a = const B().a;  // <- Lint: Invalid constant value
```

It kind of confuses me, why does `B()` can be a constant value and `B().a` is not? I would have thought if an object is a constant constructor, `B().a` would have been a constant value too.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It kind of confuses me, why does `B()` can be a constant value not `B().a` is not? I would have thought if an object is a constant constructor, `B().a` would have been a constant value too.

Dart does not have an equivalent of `constexpr` like in C++.  Dart has no way of conveying that methods/functions can be computed and invoked as compile-time constant expressions.

`B().a` invokes a getter named `a` on `B()`.  Just because `const B()` is a `const` object does not mean that `const B().a` returns a constant value.  For example, `B`'s implementation could be:

```dart
class B {
  const B();

  // Returns a new `A` instance each time.
  A get a => A();
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Is there a away to specify this getter is a final and constant value then? Or there is nothing I can do?

Comment: As I said, Dart currently has no way to convey that, so there is nothing you can do.