# Flutter: how to create a constant/final array so I can use the values in switch statement?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this:

```
final categories = ["First", "Second"];
```

then I want to use it like this:

```
modify(String category) {
  switch (category):
    case categories[0]: ... break;
    case categories[1]: ... break;
    default: ... break
}
```

But `Case expressions must be constant.`

How to initialize a constant array? Is it possible in Dart?

Comment: @GrahamD That won't help because [`categories[0]` still won't be a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67864920/).

Comment: @stacktrace2234 As explained in the referenced question above, it's not possible to use `List` elements as constants.  You will need to use `if` statements.  Depending on what your case bodies are doing, maybe you could use a `Map<String, void Function<void>>` instead, although that likely would not be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You should use enum

```
enum Category {
  category1,
  category2,
  category3

}
void modify(Category category) {
  switch (category) {
    case Category.category1:
      break;    
    case Category.category2:
      break;    
    case Category.category3:
      break;    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Common fixes:**

Either make the expression a constant expression, or rewrite the switch statement as a sequence of if statements:

```dart
modify(String category) {
  if (category == categories[0]) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

`categories` here is a `List` object, unlike array in c,c++ or java. And square bracket call is shorthand for `categories.get(index)` in java.
That Function is **not** fundamentally const, so its not possible to use in switch case, like in java arrays.

Comment: Yeah, nice copy pasting. How to make the expression a constant expression?

Comment: replace final with `const` keyword

Comment: @p2kr As I mentioned in comments to the question, that won't help.

Comment: What stacktrace2234 is looking for is impossible because categories[0] are similar to calling a function like categories.getAt(0). And that function is not fundamentally const as it is evaluated at runtime. It's limitation of switch case in most languages